# Why I am getting re-render errors on loading page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created an app that consists of a loading screen. However, if the API is failed after 5 seconds, a failure message is to be conveyed. I am getting too-many re-renders error on the line which I have mentioned in the code below.

I have used setTimeout function to replace the message of failure if API fails after 5 seconds of loading the page. The rest of my app functionality is working fine.

My app code is: -

```
function App() {

  //Is website loaded for first time?
  const [loadingFirstTime, setLoadingFirstTime] = useState(true);
  //Has the  site  loading  failed? If yes, pass that to loading component
  const [loadingFailed, setLoadingFailed] = useState(false);

  //To be run first time the website is loaded
  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies()
        .then(res => setMoviesDetails(res))
        .then(() => setLoadingFirstTime(false)); 
  }, [])

  ................... some code here .............


  //If the details of api haven't been loaded or api loading failed
  if (Object.keys(moviesDetails).length === 0 && loadingFirstTime) {

    //------**Error occurs here after 5 seconds as per the console**-----------------
    
    //check for the same thing after 5 seconds, if initial data still has been loaded?
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (Object.keys(moviesDetails).length === 0 && loadingFirstTime) {
        setLoadingFailed(true);
      }
    }, 5000);

    return (
      <LoadingScreen status={loadingFailed} />
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      ........ App components which are working fine .............
    </>
  );
}
```

Code for my loading component: -

```
function LoadingScreen({status}) {

    const [loadingText, setLoadingText] = useState("Loading the site...");

    //check if site loading failed and display appropiate message
    if (status) {
        setLoadingText("Website loading failed. Please reload or contact the administrator.");
    }

    return (
        <div className="loading-screen">
            <h1>{loadingText}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you should avoid changing states when rendering, which is what you are doing in your LoadingScreen component when you are setting loadingText.

```
setLoadingText("Website loading failed. Please reload or contact the administrator.");
```

This is happening all the time you are passing a truthy value to status. That line is making LoadingScreen component to re-render itself again and again in an infinite loop.

Generally, it is better to implement this feature inside a useEffect function like this one:

```
function LoadingScreen({ status }) {
  const [loadingText, setLoadingText] = useState("Loading the site...");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status) {
      const newLoadingText =
        "Website loading failed. Please reload or contact the administrator.";

      if (newLoadingText !== loadingText) {
        // This state setter provokes a re-render so set only if new value is
        // different than the actual value stored in state
        setLoadingText(newLoadingText);
      }
    }
  }, [loadingText, status]);

  return (
    <div className="loading-screen">
      <h1>{loadingText}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```